# unable to start exe file with pyside Qprocess

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qprocess

I'm unable to start an exe file from pyside GUI,
I tried to browse for an exe file and open it but I can see qprocess documentation are too few and I can't find out a way to run this correctly

*Here is my code*

```
   def run_automatch(self):
    file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Single File', 
                                                       QtCore.QDir.currentPath(),'*.exe')
    p = QProcess()
    p.setProgram(file_path)
    p.setWorkingDirectory(QtCore.QDir.currentPath())
    p.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably caused because "p" is a local variable so it will be destroyed as soon as run_automatch is finished. A possible solution is to create a list that is an attribute of the class and that stores the QProcesses:

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    # ...

    self.processes = []

def run_automatch(self):
    file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
        self, "Single File", QtCore.QDir.currentPath(), "*.exe"
    )
    if not file_path:
        return

    p = QProcess()
    p.setProgram(file_path)
    p.setWorkingDirectory(QtCore.QDir.currentPath())
    p.start()

    self.processes.append(p)
```

Comment: tried this and added print statement for both p and processes list output was as follow <PySide2.QtCore.QProcess(0x16732b8bae0) at 0x000001672FFD1BC0>
[<PySide2.QtCore.QProcess(0x16732b8bae0) at 0x000001672FFD1BC0>]     and the exe file didnt work

Comment: @HoussamFarag I do not understand your comment, explain yourself better since otherwise it will be impossible to help you

Comment: def run_automatch(self):
        file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Single File', QtCore.QDir.currentPath(), '*.exe')
        p = QProcess()
        p.setProgram(file_path)
        p.setWorkingDirectory(QtCore.QDir.currentPath())
        p.start()
        print(p)
        self.processes.append(p)
        print(self.processes)

Comment: @HoussamFarag Returned with the same, I will not answer anything until you comment something coherent, I will continue on my way. With that type of comments you discourage to help you. What does "the exe file didnt work" mean? If you want more help then you must provide a [mre] since it may be that the error is in the part that you do not show.

Comment: i added the process list to class init and added 2 print statement for the p and for the processes list , the output as you can see in the first comment showing the process and list of processes but the exe file havent get executed

Comment: @HoussamFarag As I told you in the previous comment: If you want more help then provide a [mre], otherwise, bye. How do you know the .exe won't run? What do you expect to see when an .exe runs?

Comment: i used the same code you provided and browsed for cmd.exe as far as i think i should see the cmd window, and this is not happening

Comment: i tried this with windows calculator exe and it worked , i will dig to see what is wrong with my exe files , thanks a lot eyllanesc

Comment: PySide2.QtCore.QProcess.ProcessState.NotRunning this is what i get with my exe file and even cmd.exe

Comment: it is working in the background as i tried to execute some database inserts but not show the in the cmd window as it normally behaves with double click

Comment: Much appreciated